# Highlight differences between 2 data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, comparison

Is there any method to compare 2 data frames in R

I want a visual comparision where I can see both data fames and the differences are highlighted, similar to when I compare two paragraphs

My purpose to compare is that there may be some values different or missing, extra rows from the result I should be getting.

Comment: https://waldo.r-lib.org/

Comment: After comparing I see the major difference causing the error

old$country` is an S3 object of class <factor>, an integer vector
new$country` is a character vector ('Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', 'Argentina', ...)

How should I correct the new one to make it similar to old one ?

Comment: as.character(FACTOR_VARIABLE)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **compareDF** package. The two dataframes to be compared must have the same columns structure.

```r
library(compareDF)

df1 <- iris[1:5, ]
df1$Species <- as.character(df1$Species) # "unfactor"
df2 <- df1
df2[1, 1] <-10
df2[2, 5] <- "tulip"

# create comparison object
comp <- compare_df(df1, df2)

# visualize it in a "git diff" style
create_output_table(comp)
```

[image]

```r
# wide format
create_wide_output(comp)
#   rowname Species_old Species_new Sepal.Width_old Sepal.Width_new
# 1       1      setosa      setosa             3.5             3.5
# 2       2       tulip      setosa             3.0             3.0
#   Sepal.Length_old Sepal.Length_new Petal.Width_old Petal.Width_new
# 1             10.0              5.1             0.2             0.2
# 2              4.9              4.9             0.2             0.2
#   Petal.Length_old Petal.Length_new
# 1              1.4              1.4
# 2              1.4              1.4
```

You can also use the [**dataCompareR**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dataCompareR/vignettes/dataCompareR.html) package (see the vignette).